# overflow div in the middle of the page finish scrolling before the body starts scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to add a div that has an overflow scroll attribute, be incorporated into the body scroll.

For example,
when scrolling down to page 1 to 3, My page 2 contains an overflow: scroll div. The behavior I am trying to achieve is the moment the beginning of page 2 reaches the top, the body stops scrolling, while the div inside MUST finish scrolling down, before continuing down to page 3.

```css
.containerPage1 {
    min-height: 100vh;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    color: black;
}
.container {
     min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    width: 100%
}

.leftDiv {
     position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px green solid;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 3;
    margin: 5;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
   /*  background-color: grey; */
    
}

.rightDiv {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    
 overflow: scroll;
    border: 15px red solid;
    z-index: 1;
}

.innerRightDiv {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 47%;
    float: right;
    border: 10px green solid;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerPage1">
  <div>
      hi
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="leftDiv">
     <div>stuff</div><div>stuff</div><div>stuff</div>
     <div>stuff</div><div>stuff</div><div>stuff</div>
     <div>stuff</div><div>stuff</div><div>stuff</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="rightDiv">
    <div class="innerRightDiv">
        <div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div>
        <div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div>
        <div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div>
        <div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div><div>page3</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


<div class="containerPage1">
  <div>
      hi
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mnguyen106/cja56bez/)

So in this demo, the green box has its own scrollable and its possible to scroll down before completing the green box has reached the end.

This can most likely be fixed with javascript, however, I have no idea where to start anchoring a page.

Comment: I think your code works... depending on where the scroll capture occurs. Having scrollable containers within scrollable containers seems to always have peculiar behaviors.

Comment: That scroll again happens where the user points the cursor if he points to the second page then your code works as is, you can explain in detail if I am missing anything here.

Comment: @Manjuboyz
Yes, the code works when the cursor is anywhere inside the red box, this layout is the closest I can get to my desired behavior. 

My question is when scrolling down from page 1 to 3, how to get the beginning of page 2 to become fixed onto the screen until page 2 is fully scrolled all the way down. then the page may continue scrolling down normally to page 3. (regardless of where the cursor is.). If you need another explanation, there's a working website I can show you which I am trying to emulate from. Visit https://thierrychopain.com/  and you'll know what I'm talking about

Comment: If I had to guess, that website is using [sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) headers/containers in each section. The page, as a whole, is still scrolling (*you can see the scroll handle in the scrollbar continually move*) and it's only when the container the sticky element is in is scrolling off the screen it "pushes" the "stuck" container with it. Have you examined the  applied CSS of that website in your browser's dev tools?

Comment: @Drew Reese
Thank you, It was something as simple as just using sticky.
I was able to make that scrolling effect by placing two divs beside each other and making one of them sticky..

Comment: Great! You should answer here.

Comment: @DrewReese it was your answer, haha you should put one

Comment: Mine was only a suggestion/hunch. *Your* solution is what is working. You can answer and accept your answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I was looking for was simply setting the left div with a stick position. This would give the effect of half the page is scrolling.

I changed the original css to float the two inner divs side by side instead of setting the inner divs to display inline-block.

`inline-block` does not allow position to be set as a sticky.

CSS

```
.containerPage1 {
  min-height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: black;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
}
.inner-div {
  float: left;
  border: 2px yellow solid;
  width: 45%;  
}
.inner-div-content {
  padding: 50px;
}
.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="containerPage1">
  <div>
    page1
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-div sticky">
    <div class="inner-div-content">
      Tite here
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class= "inner-div">
    <div class="inner-div-content">
      <p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p>
      <p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p>
      <p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p>
      <p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p><p>Content text </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>


<div class="containerPage1">
  <div>
    PAGE3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main_container{
  height:100vh;
  overflow-y:scroll
}
```

```html
<div class='main_container' >

</div>
```

when your div exceed to 100 vh it will automaticlaly scrollable